# Receiving responses in Android from a Spring REST service

Tags: android, spring, rest

I'm working with Android on the front end and I'm using Spring's REST Client libraries to send HTTP Requests to a REST web service. I've read examples online where people use `AsyncTask` to accomplish this with a `RestTemplate` in `doInBackground` method of `AsyncTask`, but I've also read examples where `RestTemplate` is used outside of `AsyncTask`, even in an activity or fragment. Is there any point in using one method over the other?

Secondly, when receiving a response from the server through RestTemplate's `exchange` or `getForAllObject`, based on the data received my client should be doing different things. For example, if I want to search for users, I should receive `User` objects and then my client should then update the users fragment/activity, but if I want to login, I should receive different data and my client should perform different subsequent tasks.

If I create an AsyncTask every time I send an HTTP Request and then receive the response, how can I distinguish what subsequent tasks need to be done client-side? Is the preferred method to use enums? For eg., when I want to get data from a server, I can instantiate an AsyncTask and pass as `execute` parameters an enum to specify which HTTP request to send and an enum to specify what to do with received data. Then I could just use switch statements which call different functions based on the enum?

If none of this makes sense, is there a more standard way to approach handling responses from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

AsyncTask provides a convenient way to do tasks in background and interact with the main UI thread. If you did not use AsyncTasks you have to implement your own methods to synchronize with the main thread to update the UI. If you are calling any back end services or doing long running operations, it is always good to go with async tasks.

It is a bad practice to have your same REST end point to return different objects based on an enum. Have two separate endpoints. One GET call to search users and one POST call to login users. In the client side also have separate implementations on consuming above endpoints. Use them appropriately when needed.

Comment: I'm still unsure how this works. If I have a function to send a GET request and a function to send a POST request, wouldn't both of these functions be instantiating a class that extends AsyncTask to run in the background to send the request and receive the response? So then during the call to `onPostExecution`, how would AsyncTask know where to go from there, not knowing whether the initial HTTP request was a POST or GET request? Would I need to instead extend an AsyncTask for every type of HTTP request I wish to send (one for logging in, one for getting x data, one for getting y data)?

Comment: You have to have two separate async taskts. As an Example UserSearchAsyncTask and UserLoginAsyncTask. both classes extends AsyncTask. Then each class where necessary. Normally, you have separate activities or fragments to handle these two scenarios.